# gcc using gnu++14 fails to locate member function in templated class

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a class template `Numlike<T>::type` that contains a member function `value`, of type `() -> T`. `Numlike<T>` is a struct that I'm using so I can write `Numlike<T>::type` as a visual cue that the template expands into a class, not sure if that's idiomatic. `g++`, with the `--std=gnu++14`, flag doesn't seem to be able to locate this member function, and produces an error:

```
% g++ -std=gnu++14 numlike_test.cc
numlike_test.cc: In function 'int main()':
numlike_test.cc:7:19: error: 'class Numlike<int>::type' has no member named 'value'
   std::cout << hi.value() << std::endl;;
                   ^~~~~
Exit 1
```

However, the `c++98`, `c++11`, and `c++14` standards, as well as `gnu++11`, are all able to locate the member function. A final piece of evidence is that `clang++ -std=gnu++14 numlike_test.cc` also compiles without error. `g++-mp-5` also doesn't exhibit this behavior.

Here's the header file

```
// numlike.hpp
template <class T> struct Numlike {
  class type {
  private:
    T t;

  public:
    // nullary constructor, should produce 0 for numbers ... maybe?
    type() { this->t = T(); }
    // throw an error if we try to pass in a different type
    // of number, don't convert!
    explicit type(const T &t) { this->t = t; }
    // get the value back out
    T value() { return this->t; }
  };
};
```

And here's the source file, `numlike_test.cc`.

```
// numlike_test.cc
#include "numlike.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Numlike<int>::type hi;
  std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;;
  std::cout << hi.value() << std::endl;;
}
```

What's happening with GCC?
Tested using GCC version 6.3 on OS X.

```
% g++ --version
g++ (MacPorts gcc6 6.3.0_2) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

% md5 `which g++`
MD5 (/opt/local/bin/g++) = e9ee41c449064eba1e07ea00d76895be
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/g/Kvv5ya)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It works fine with gcc 6.3.0.